# Access a Wrapper Class/list from a Different Class?

Tags: apex, java

So this is what I'm trying to do.  I want to make a new class as an extension to a VF Page, and be able to access List Values from that class, that are created in another class.  Like so:

```
public with sharing class CLASSONE{


public list <wrapper> wrapObj {get;set;}

controller  public CLASSONE(){

     WrapObj = new list<wrapper>(); }

public class WRAPPER{ //make wrapper here }

}
```

This wrapper is populated in the class, and used in the VF page below.

```
<apex:page Controller="CLASSONE" extensions="CLASSTWO">
```

I have too many things going on in the CLASS ONE, so I was hoping to make a second class for new functionality, so I can keep things neat.  How do I do this:

```
    public with sharing class CLASSTWO{

private CLASSONE someName = new CLASSONE();
public classone.wrapper classTwoWrap = new classone.wrapper();


//controller
public CLASS TWO (CLASSONE sc2){

classTwoWrap = new classone.wrapper();
classTwoWrap = classone.wrapObj[0];

}
```

Does that make sense what I'm trying to do?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference a public inner class like `WRAPPER` very much like a top level class from a different class such as `CLASSTWO` using `CLASSONE.WRAPPER`. An inner class instance is independent of the top level class it is defined in so can be referenced and used very much like a top level class.

It is possible to write a controller extension for a non-standard controller, as [Building a Controller Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) mentions, so the extension can reference data from the controller:

```
// Custom controller
public with sharing class CLASSONE {
    public class WRAPPER {
        // ...
    }
    public list <WRAPPER> wrapObj {get;set;}
    public CLASSONE() {
        WrapObj = new list<wrapper>();
        // List must be populated here if extension is to grab values in its constructor
    }
}

// Custom controller extension
public with sharing class CLASSTWO {
    private CLASSONE c1;
    public CLASSONE.WRAPPER classTwoWrap;
    public CLASSTWO(CLASSONE c1) {
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.classTwoWrap = c1.wrapObj[0];
    }
}
```

But read documentation such as [Considerations for Creating Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_considerations.htm) and be aware of [Order of Execution for Visualforce Page Get Requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_get_request.htm).

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for the code example and the further readings.  Now I know what to look for.  Thanks Keith!

Comment: Follow up:  So if the wrapper is populated with data in a separate function, I won't be able to get that data since it hasn't been populated in the constructor?  I will just get the initial constructor values of the ClassOne wrapper?